# Qt Creator -> Qt Quick Application (QML) -> Design Tab -> Missing "Window"

Tags: qt, qml, qt-designer

In Design tab the "Window" is missing.

When I click the Design tab -> pop up three windows. [three windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz1RS.jpg)

After I close one -> disappear all of them.[window title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeeIl.jpg)

It doesn't work when I try to drag and drop basic component's...

I reinstall the Qt Creator but the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following bugreport https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-26486

Here are some key points from the comments.

Three things you shouldn't have done:

1. Enable the QmlDesigner plugin (isn't officially supported by Qt Creator anymore, you can use Qt Design Studio)
2. Open a non-.ui.qml file in QmlDesigner
3. Open a file with a QtQuick.Window root element, which is not fully endorsed in QmlDesigner.

> Support for Qt 5.15 requires a "kit" with a qml2puppet for Qt 5.15.
> This setup is only properly supported and tested in Qt Design Studio.
> If you use Qt Creator the puppet will be always built with the same Qt
> version as Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator states are kept in the following locations:

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\QtProject and %LOCALAPPDATA%\QtProject\QtCreator`
- Linux: `$HOME/.config/QtProject`
- macOS: `$HOME/.config/QtProject`

Please review those locations and backup/rename/clean up.
You should find this restores your Qt Creator to 'factory' conditions.