# Qt Creator 10.0.1, opens 3 qml puppet windows when on design mode

Tags: qml, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator 10.0.1 (Community) on Windows 11. I need to edit my .qml files in design mode. When I enable the qmldesigner plugin and try to open design mode, it opens three popup windows of my application. When I close these windows, I am not able to edit in the design mode. This bug has been already raised in qt bug reports but there seems to be no solution.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454733/qt-creator-qt-quick-application-qml-design-tab-missing-window